# How to stack components on another so that they'd keep their vertical size?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, layout-manager

I have a parent JPanel with child components which are stacked on another. However they do not resize as I'd like to:

[This is how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIoJM.png)

[This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAVHz.png)

Code:

```
public class LayoutTest extends JFrame {

public LayoutTest() {
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 50));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        panel.setBackground(Color.red);
        getContentPane().add(panel);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LayoutTest layoutTest = new LayoutTest();
}
```

}

The problem mainly is that the components resize vertically when they should not. I'd like them to keep their vertical dimension, but they won't. I've tried multiple layouts e.g. GridBagLayout, FlowLayout, BoxLayout, but none of them worked.

My best try has been with BoxLayout:

Simply: `container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);`
and then `container.add(component1)`...

Any help is appreciated.

Working solution by camickr:

```
public class LayoutTest extends JFrame {

public LayoutTest() {
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    JPanel container = new JPanel();
    container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 50));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        panel.setBackground(Color.red);
        container.add(panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    }
    getContentPane().add(container, BorderLayout.NORTH);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LayoutTest layoutTest = new LayoutTest();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A BoxLayout will grow components up to there maximum size when space is available.

When you add your panel to the frame, instead of adding it to the CENTER, which would allow the panel to grow, you add it to the PAGE_START which will respect the height:

```
JPanel north = new JPanel();
north.setLayout( new BoxLayout(north, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS) );
// add loop to add panels to the "north" panel

add(north, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

Another solution is to wrap the panel using a box layout into another panel.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout( new BoxLayout(panel. BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS) );
// create your loop to add child panels

JPanel wrapper = new JPanel(); // uses FlowLayout by default which respects the preferred size.
wrapper.add( panel );
frame.add( wrapper );
```

Comment: I cannot get either one of these to work. Can you provide me an example program?

Comment: *"I cannot get either one of these to work"* Why? What error you get? *"Can you provide me an example program?"* I ask you the same, can you post an [mre] that shows how you implemented these suggestions? And explain why they don't work for you?

Comment: Fair enough, modified.

Comment: *I cannot get either one of these to work.* - Where is the code that implemented either of my suggestions??? Don't change the layout of the content panel! Don't add components directly to the content pane! Instead  create a panel that you want to add the the "north" part of the frame that uses the BoxLayout. Then add components to this "north" panel.  When you are finished adding components, add the "north" panel to the frame using the appropriate constraint for the BorderLayout. See update code for basic structure.

Comment: I got it working using your first example. I'll update above. Thank you very much!